# Can I use '= ALL' in SQL Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to use an `'= ALL'` using a parameter and a set of results from a sub-query, like this:

```
SELECT table.something
FROM Table t
WHERE t.param = ALL (... sub-query...)
```

is this possible? because I know what the result should be and I'm not getting any results at all...

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/all-subqueries.html

Comment: With that syntax you will get only the results for whom param is equal to all the elements returned by the sub-query.

Comment: What's `t.param`?  Wouldn't it have to be an array or something?

Comment: It may help to illustrate what you'd expect for some given inputs, as it's not crystal clear what you're expecting.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/all-subqueries.html

If you're not getting the results you expect, I'm guessing there is an issue with the query. The way it is currently written, all of the results in the sub-query must match `t.param`'s value (which doesn't make a whole lot of sense out of context).

Comment: Wow - the *ALL* completely passed me by.  That could come in useful for a couple of things I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

It's only makes sense if the subquery only ever returns a single value.

If the subquery returns more than one value, you will not get any matching rows. There is no value that can be equal to two other values simultaneously.

If the subquery for example returns 1 and 2, and your table contains the value 2, it won't match because the value 2 is not equal to both 1 and 2.

So, using the `ALL` keyword with the `=` operator is actually pretty useless. I think that you want to use the `ANY` keyword or the `IN` operator instead.

Comment: "It's only makes sense if the subquery only ever returns a single value." -- Can you clarify what you mean, please. Consider: `SELECT t.ID FROM MyTable t WHERE t.ID = ALL (SELECT t2.ID FROM MyTable t2 WHERE t2.ID = t.ID);` -- is the subquery really only returning one value here?

Comment: @onedaywhen: I don't know what it is that you find unclear, you have to specify... Yes, the subquery is only returning one value in your example. The subquery is depending on the value from each specific row, so it will be executed once for each row in `t`, and each time the value of `t2.ID` can not be anything other than equal to `t.ID`, as that is what you specified in the condition.

Comment: "it will be executed once for each row in t, and each time the value of t2.ID" -- so if there are three distinct values for `ID` in `MyTable` then the same subquery  will return three different values, right? That is quite different from "only ever returns a single value", don't you think?

Comment: @onedaywhen: No, it's not. To "only ever return a single value" is not the same as to "always return the same single value".

Answer (score -1):

This is the general form used, I've not heard of `ALL`:

```
SELECT table.something
FROM Table t
WHERE t.param IN (SELECT param FROM Table2 WHERE somecriteria='somevalue')
```

For a `names` table of this:

```
ID | firstname 
---+----------
 1 | alice
 2 | bob
 3 | jane
 4 | sue
```

The query:

```
SELECT * FROM names WHERE firstname in ('alice', 'jane');
```

Will return this:

```
ID | firstname 
---+----------
 1 | alice
 3 | jane
```

Comment: but does it match my parameter with all the results from the sub-query?

Comment: Yes, if your sub-query returns 6 rows `1,6,2,6,11,56`, then all your `table` records with any of those `param` values will be returned.

Comment: As with RaymondHettinger's answer, this is equivalent to ANY, not ALL.